# Filtering DataTable and copying results to two different DataTables

Tags: c#, datatable, enumerable

I'm trying to filter results from a method that returns a DataTable, by a certain column value (of type DateTime) and inserting them into two distinct DataTables, as follows:

```
var vAllItems = myClass.GetAllResults(x,y,z);
DataTable dtExpiredItems = new DataTable();
DataTable dtActiveItems = new DataTable();

var expiredItems = vAllItems.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<DateTime?>("ExpDate") <= DateTime.Now && r.Field<DateTime?>("ExpDate").HasValue);
var activeItems = vAllItems.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<DateTime?>("ExpDate") > DateTime.Now || !r.Field<DateTime?>("ExpDate").HasValue);

foreach(DataRow row in expiredItems)
     dtExpiredItems.Rows.Add(row);

foreach (DataRow row in activeItems)
     dtActiveItems.Rows.Add(row);

rptExpiredItems.DataSource = dtExpiredItems;
rptExpiredItems.Bind();
pchExpiredItems.Visible = dtExpiredItems.Rows.Count > 0;

rptActiveItems.DataSource = dtActivetItems;
rptActiveItems.Bind();
pchActiveItems.Visible = dtActiveItems.Rows.Count > 0;
```

Thing is, on the second foreach loop the following error occurs:

```
This row already belongs to another table.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: This row already belongs to another table.
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: DateTime.Now()  is constantly changing.  You want to set it to a variable before your queries.  In theory expireditems and activeitems should not have the same rows from vAllItems (except if the DataTime is null).  So I think the issue is occurring because of the null DataTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DataRow can only belong to a one `DataTable`, you should create a new row from given row values.

Use `ItemArray` property of the `DataRow` to get values and pass `object[]` as an input to create new row.

```
dtExpiredItems.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
```

or use `ImportRow`

```
dtExpiredItems.ImportRow(row);
```

Another option is using [`CopyToDataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx) (DataTable)extension to create new table from `Linq` output, then use new table for your binding.

```
dtExpiredItems = expiredItems.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Comment: Thank you Hari, marked as correct. Althought item count verification is needed before calling the CopToDataTable method!

Answer (score 1):

Where you are doing the following

```
dtExpiredItems.Rows.Add(row);
dtActiveItems.Rows.Add(row);
```

You could instead do

```
dtExpiredItems.ImportRow(row);
dtActiveItems.ImportRow(row);
```